# How to leverage sharepoint cascading using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, jsom, js

I have a parent list called called Items List residing on parent site containing columns as Site and Workspace. I created a Site Lookup column and named it as 'Workspace' which references Workspace column from the Items List. Then I am using this 'Workspace' site lookup column in Documents library on subsites under parent.

I have about 5 subsites under root. The Site column in the Items list contains these subsite names like Site 1, Site 2, Site 3, Site 4, Site 5 and relevant workspace names are stored in Workspace column. Below is the screenshot of the list.

[image]

Now the challenge is let's say if I am working on Documents Library (It has Worksapce added from existing site columns) under subsite Site 1 then in the Workspace drop-down, I would only want to see Workspace names that are relevant to Site 1 which are Workspace 1, Workspace 2 and Workspace 4 and others should be hidden. Similarly If user is working on Site 2's documents library then he/she should only see Workspace 6 in the Workspace drop-down. So this should be dynamic in nature, like if anything changes in the Items list, the drop-down should account for that.

I already achieved this using SPServices but unfortunately I won't be able to proceed with it since it was not approved as a solution. I have to somehow achieve this using JavaScript or JSLink since I am working with SharePoint online, please help with the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If creating an SPFx webpart is part of your solution, then there is [a tutorial](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-cascading-dropdowns-in-web-part-properties.md) explaining just about that for a web part property pane.

Later on, you can probably make a combination of the [React List Form Webpart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form) and the cascading properties effect to make your own SPFx web part.

Comment: Hi Deepu, I am not looking a solution for Modern UI, it has to be for classic SharePoint.

Comment: No worries. I can suggest this article - https://kogzee.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/cascading-dropdowns-on-large-lists-in-sharepoint-using-jslink/ -  to try with JSLink. I haven't done this before, so please try it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks Deepu, the only issue here is the drop down does not show pre-filtered options based on what site user is working on, users will have to type and look for it which is not ideal. ANy other suggestions using JS?